# Book - society of humanoid people that practise open relationships until they reach a certain age then have a monogamous partner

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

I think they lived kind of adjacent to a human race that had technology. They were the protagonists of the story. I read it around 20 years ago and it was probably about 15-30 years old then. They possibly lived in a jungle-like setting and there was a feeling of some kind of magic.